# Google Maps - Displaying traffic for polyline

Tags: android, google-maps, google-polyline

Is it possible to display traffic only for polyline drawn, instead of adding traffic layer which displays **on top** of my polyline?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. You can use [Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro) to get your route and analyze response. In the response you get path polyline, `"distance"` and `"duration"` tags for each leg/step of path, e.g.:

```
...
"distance": {
    "text": "1.8 mi",
    "value": 2856
},
"duration": {
    "text": "10 mins",
    "value": 570
},
...
```

and you can calculate `speed = distance.value / duration.value`. Then you can set color for polyline depending on calculated speed. E.g. if `speed < 10` - set `Color.RED` color for polyline,  `10 <= speed < 30` - `Color.YELLOW`, etc.

Comment: this only works A to B (since the polyline might not have any way-points) and there's no guarantee the same route would be returned.

Comment: @MartinZeitler Of course that is not even information about traffic - just it's duration-based estimation. This should works for any part of route where `"polyline"`, `"distance"` and `"duration"` tags are set. Same route can be provided by additional waypoints in directions request. And anyway: seems there is no other way to estimate traffic for polyline via Google Maps API.